# Pushing UIViewController fails with "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

So I'm using a NavigationController to do all the navigation of my iOS App. On the main screen there is a 'plus button' to take an image, and on pressing this button the NavigationController pushes the 'CameraViewController' with the method 'displayCamera:'. There the user can take an image and it is supposed to be previewed by another UIViewController which is pushed by the function 'picTaken:'. However overtime I try to push this view controller I get the error "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target". I have no idea what is going wrong. Below is the NavigationController.h and the corresponding .m file

---

NavigationController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "PictureCheckViewController.h"

@interface NavigationController : UINavigationController {
    CameraViewController *camView;
    MainViewController *mainView;
    PictureCheckViewController *checkView;
}

- (void)displayCamera:(id)sender;

- (void)picTaken:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

NavigationController.m

```
#import "NavigationController.h"

@interface NavigationController () {

}

@end

@implementation NavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    camView = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];
    mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    checkView = [[PictureCheckViewController alloc] init];

}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)displayCamera:(id)sender {
    [self pushViewController:camView animated:YES];
}

- (void)picTaken:(id)sender {
    [self pushViewController:checkView animated:YES];
}

@end
```

If you need anymore information please tell me.

I appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you call picTaken?

Comment: Hey sorry, I just noticed I didn't clarify that. First of all to open the cameraView I call the function `displayCamera:` and it works fine, no issue. The problem arises when I later want to call `picTaken:` and then it throws the error. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Can you check, with a breakpoint if the instance is actually nil?

Comment: So I just checked with 2 breakpoints. The point where I alloc, and init the breakpoint prints the instance. However my second breakpoint in the function prints nil. Why would this be happening? Should I add them as properties instead and make them strong connections?

Comment: The iVars should be strong references. Are you using ARC? You should.

Comment: So I just declare them in the header in the `@interface`. Should I set them as properties instead with a strong retain? And to clarify what do you mean by iVars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use a lazy instantiation method.
Add a property :

```
@Property(nonatomic,strong) MainViewController *mainView;
@Property(nonatomic,strong) PictureCheckViewController *checkView;
```

and override the getters yourself:

```
-(MainViewController*) mainView {
    if(!_mainView) {
        _mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return _mainView;
}
```

And like wise for checkView.

```
-(PictureCheckViewController*) checkView {
    if(!_checkView) {
        _checkView = [[PictureCheckViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return _checkView;
}
```

then access using:

```
self.checkView
self.mainView
```

Aside from I believe fixing your problem, it would also avoid creation unless the resource is actually used.

Comment: Yes that worked, I don't get the error. The view still doesn't appear, but I will continue debugging and try to figure out why. Thank you very much! Just as extra information, since I just teach myself coding myself, why is this why the lazy instantiation? What would the non lazy way be? And why is it best to override the getters instead of using `@synthesize`? Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate the quick responses.

Comment: Certainly. It is lazy because you _are_ overriding it. The value is not initialised until the first time it is requested (hence the if statement). Remember that swift(and modern objective-c since iOS 5 i think) is auto synthesised anyway. If you don't call the getter the value is never set. and its cached thereafter.